# Why do we need to soak dry Fenugreek leaves in warm water, and then sprinkle salt over them?

Tags: herbs, soaking

**What's the benefit of soaking dry Fenugreek leaves in warm water and then sprinkling salt over them?**

From: http://www.everestspices.com/masalas/kasuri-methi

> **Soak the Everest Kasuri Methi in boiling water with a pinch of salt**.

From: http://www.rakskitchen.net/2010/07/dal-fry.html

> add kasuri methi leaves(**soak in hot water before adding**)at this stage.

From: http://www.tarladalal.com/Aloo-Methi-%28-Punjabi-Recipe%29-22789r

> Wash the fenugreek leaves and chop them finely. **Sprinkle some salt over them** and keep aside for about half an hour.

Answer (score 3):

**Why we add fenugreek leaves in dishes:**

Normally in Indian dishes we used to add herbs for removing common health issues,the benefits of adding fenugreek leave and indian herbs while cooking can be seen here:

http://chefinyou.com/ingredients/what-is-fenugreek/  (for new users: what is it and what uses it has)

http://www.indiamart.com/glittoexports/spices-leaves-spices-3.html (indian common herbs)

**Why we sprinkle salt after soaking in hot water:**

Normally hot water is capable to remove the common uncleaned strains... and some common small microbacteria (as normally this kind of herbs were grown under muddy conditions so there were more chances for microbacteria's)

We used to sprinkle salt over herbal leaves for mainly two reasons:

1. To bring taste

   [Why is it important to add salt during cooking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19411/why-is-it-important-to-add-salt-during-cooking)
2. The main reason for sprinkling salt was **the herbs were normally salt absorbing interigents** so we sprinkle salt after soaking in hot water

hope it helps